# NDB index of datetime property and parenting

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I’m not completely confident in my understanding of indexes.
(comfort level: 87%)

**Does parenting affect the index location on BigTable tablets.  Or is it purely determined by kind?**

My example:

Normally, it would be a bad idea to index a datetime property if the entity kind is subject to frequent writes.

But if the parent is a fairly uniformly distributed random key, and it is unlikely that there will be 2 entities of kind Proposed() that have the same parent, would I still have an issue with a **monotonic increasing index values creating hotspots**?

(I'm using App Engine Standard, Python 2.7.)

‘''
    #...I have an entity kind like this:

```
class Proposed(ndb.Model):
    foo = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True, default=None)
    bar = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=True, default=0)
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(indexed=True, auto_now_add=True)

#… create a randomly distributed key

random_id = int(random.uniform(0, 9999999999999999))
parent_key = ndb.Key(‘Papa', random_id)

#…I parent the entity to the random key

p = Proposed(parent=parent_key)
p.foo = ‘a ball of string’
p.bar = 42
p.put()

#…and I query using inequality filter

q = Proposed.query(ndb.AND(Proposed.bar == 42,
                           Proposed.date >= start_date,
                           Proposed.date < end_date))
```

‘''

---

Documents that seemed to indicate this (ancestor) solution:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection

Describes Index hierarchy.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/indexes#index-definition-structure

"The rows of an index table are sorted first by ancestor and then by property values, in the order specified in the index definition."

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#high_readwrite_rates_to_a_narrow_key_range

"Avoid high read or write rates to Cloud Datastore keys that are lexicographically close.
Cloud Datastore is built on top of Google's NoSQL database, Bigtable, and is subject to Bigtable's performance characteristics. Bigtable scales by sharding rows onto separate tablets, and these rows are lexicographically ordered by key"

---

Alternate solutions:

1) Create a datetime string property with a random hash prepended.
2) Make the datetime string with the order reversed:  millisecond:second:minute:hour day:month:year

I see how those solutions might work querying with an equality filter, however I will be using an inequality filter on date, and I don’t see how to query a range of dates with that method.

Humble Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to go with a variant of (1) where your prefixes are well known.  If your prefixes aren't well know, you'll have difficulty querying your entities by timestamp.  If you don't want to query by timestamp, then you can disable indexing for your timestamp properties.  The [best practices guide](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#indexes) as more details.

The entity ancestor doesn't help with the monotonically increasing index value because Cloud Datastore still allows you to query by kind, e.g. `select * from Proposed order by date`.  This query doesn't use the ancestor, and thus you can derive that the index used doesn't use the ancestor.

Comment: Thank you Jim.  That was what I was afraid of.  I will need to query by x >= start_date and x < end_date.  Maybe I can find a way to make a uniformly distributed pseudo-random hash that can be prepended.

Comment: You don't need to worry about the uniform distribution of the hash, each prefix value gets another 500 writes per second at the cost of an extra query.  That said, you might be able to use the other part of your AND query.  In this case: `Proposed.query(ndb.AND(Proposed.prefixed_date > '%s-%s' % (42, start_date), Proposed.prefixed_date <= '%s-%s' % (42, end_date)`

Comment: Ahh, so it’s a little like sharding.  1) I convert my DateTimeProperty to be a StringProperty, something like  “yyyy mm dd hh mm ss”.  2) Prepend as many predetermined shards as I think I will need.  Like: “42 - yyyy mm dd hh mm ss”, “43 - yyyy mm dd hh mm ss”.  3) Then add a query for each shard.  4) As my app gets more successful, add more shards.  Ok.  I’ll give it a try.  I appreciate the help.